# Call function from dll

Tags: python, dll, dll-injection

I am writing a program and I have injected "mydll" file into the program, but I cannot call the hello function in it. How can I call the hello function? My code:

```
import os
from ctypes import *

def DLL(dll_path, pid):
    PAGE_READWRITE = 0x04
    PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = (0x00F0000 | 0x00100000 | 0xFFF)
    VIRTUAL_MEM = (0x1000 | 0x2000)
    kernel32 = windll.kernel32
    dll_len = len(dll_path)
    h_process = kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, int(pid))
    if not h_process:
        sys.exit(0)
    arg_address = kernel32.VirtualAllocEx(h_process, 0, dll_len, VIRTUAL_MEM, PAGE_READWRITE)
    written = c_int(0)
    kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(h_process, arg_address, dll_path, VIRTUAL_MEM, PAGE_READWRITE)
    h_kernel32 = kernel32.GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll")
    h_loadlib = kernel32.GetProcAddress(h_kernel32, "LoadLibraryA")
    thread_id = c_ulong(0)
    dll = kernel32.CreateRemoteThread(h_process, None, 0, h_loadlib, arg_address, 0, byref(thread_id))
    return dll

mydll = DLL("mydll.dll", os.getpid())
mydll.hello()
```